# jquery cookie , still set after clear browser history

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, internet-explorer-11

I'm using a simple script to show a popup with a checkbox to not show it again, and it works just fine, and it works perfectly to delete the cookie via the script.

My problem is that if i delete the cookies in IE11 (company browser), the cookie is still set!
So what am i missing? Is the cookie stored somewhere other than the standard directory when using jquery.cookie.js ?

I want to be able to see the popup by delete the cookie locally.

My code for reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#Cookiehandler").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
     $.cookie('the_cookie', 'no');
    }
});

window.jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     if($.cookie('the_cookie') == null) {
       $.fancybox.open('#popup_box');


} 
else {
   // placeholder
}
   });

//$.removeCookie("the_cookie"); 
//alert( $.cookie("the_cookie") );

</script>
```

Best regards,
Marcus

Comment: what's the result of `console.log($.cookie("the_cookie"))` & how do you remove that cookie ? The standard way is to use `Ctrl + Shift + Supp` shortcut or menu `Internet Options > Navigation history > Delete...`.

Comment: how u deleted the cookie?

Comment: browser history != cookie history. You need to use the clear cookies button for that. clear privacy data, whatever they call it nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way might be for you to have an administrative page with a script that deletes the cookie and just to visit that page whenever you want the cookie to be killed. That's a browser-independent method and you don't have to worry about where the cookie was stored, nor do you have to worry about doing it from a bunch of different browsers manually. Just visit the admin page from some or all of your browsers and it's done...for those browsers...while leaving the other ones alone unless you browse the kill page from them too.

Comment: Yea i thought about this as well, but i bothers me that i can't locate the actual cookie. I'll do as you suggested but i still wanna know :)